# How do you require a field based on if another field has text?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using javascript/jquery how would I make an input required based on if the input before it has a value?

I have two inputs

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Amount", id = "additionalIncome" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeSource, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeSource, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Source", id = "additionalIncomeSource" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeSource)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and If the AdditionalIncomeAmt input has a value I want the AdditionalIncomeSource to be required.  I tried doing this with !model but its not a bool so it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Yes I am using unobtrusive validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jquery you can do this like following:

```
$(function () {

$('#additionalIncome').keyup(function (){
    if($(this).val()==''){      
        $('#additionalIncomeSource').removeAttr('required');
    }
    else{
        $('#additionalIncomeSource').attr('required','required');
    }   

});
});
```

Comment: is there a way to change the default message so it reads different from "this field is required"

Comment: try like:
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Amount", id = "additionalIncome", data-val-required="your message." })

Comment: you can also try this in your model:

[Required(ErrorMessage="your message.")]
public string AdditionalIncomeAmt {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It is a total pain but I was barely able to get it working following this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22003400/703644)

At the bottom I will include some more good resources, sorry I cannot be more help. As other have said there are more packages which do a better job with this.

One thing to note is that if you use a calculation property; so that in its `getter` it calculates a value to determine requiredness, you are going to have to write that logic to manipulate that property client side.

Example: `ParkingTicketNumber` is required if `TicketType` is "Parking". So you throw a `RequiredIf` property on `ParkingTicketNumber` conditional on a third property. That third property returns true if `TicketType` === "Parking".

That is going to work GREAT server side, and terrible client side. So you need to create a hidden input for the third property and then write some jQuery/JavaScript to change that value when `TicketType` changes.

Mo Internet help:

- [MSDN Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx)
- [Another MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)
- [Github code client side](https://gist.github.com/Cyberkruz/1547191)